# QGIS vector layer labels are not showing from python script

Tags: labeling, pyqgis-3

I have a python module, where a QGIS memory vector layer is created, within the same method that creates this layer I have constructed labels using:

```
text_format = QgsTextFormat()
label = QgsPalLayerSettings()
label.fieldName = 'Description'
label.enabled = True
label.setFormat(text_format)
labeler = QgsVectorLayerSimpleLabeling(label)
layer.setLabelsEnabled(True)
layer.setLabeling(labeler)
layer.triggerRepaint()
```

And then subsequently from another Python module I add this layer to the QGIS workspace using:

```
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
```

The labels are not showing in QGIS, however, if I open the "Labels" dialogue from within QGIS and press "Apply" then the labels show.  So I assume that the label field and text is set properly.

**I have repeated the problem described above in the Python console** within QGIS v3.2.2 using the following script:

```
from qgis.core import *

layer=QgsVectorLayer('MultiLineString?crs=epsg:4326&field=ID:string&field=Description:string', "MultiLines", "memory")
pr=layer.dataProvider()
record = QgsFeature()
record.setAttributes(['1','test'])
record.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromWkt('MULTILINESTRING ((1 1, 6 1))'))
pr.addFeature(record)

text_format = QgsTextFormat()
label = QgsPalLayerSettings()
label.fieldName = 'Description'
label.enabled = True
label.setFormat(text_format)
labeler = QgsVectorLayerSimpleLabeling(label)
layer.setLabelsEnabled(True)
layer.setLabeling(labeler)
layer.triggerRepaint()

QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
```

Any suggestions on what I need to add to my python script to have the labels show?

QGIS v3.2.2-Bonn was used.

Comment: Works fine for me (tested on QGIS 3.4 for Win7-64bit). Which version are you using and how are you running your script?

Comment: I am using QGIS version 3.2.2-Bonn. I am running my script via a QGIS plugin that I created.

Comment: Do you think it would make a difference if I created the labels after adding the vector layer to the QGIS worksapce?

Comment: You could try adding the labels after adding the layer and see if it makes a difference. I tested the code using the Python Console so would be interesting to see if, via a plugin, the layer needs to be added first before you can set labels.

Comment: I have added a python script which gives the same problem when run from the Python Console

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try defining the label placement as `Line`:

```
text_format = QgsTextFormat()
label = QgsPalLayerSettings()
label.fieldName = 'Description'
label.enabled = True
label.setFormat(text_format)

# --
label.placement = QgsPalLayerSettings.Line
# --

labeler = QgsVectorLayerSimpleLabeling(label)
layer.setLabelsEnabled(True)
layer.setLabeling(labeler)
layer.triggerRepaint()
```

After testing it also seems to work before adding the layer to the canvas in the standalone script.

```
from qgis.core import *

layer=QgsVectorLayer('MultiLineString?crs=epsg:4326&field=ID:string&field=Description:string', "MultiLines", "memory")
pr=layer.dataProvider()
record = QgsFeature()
record.setAttributes(['1','test'])
record.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromWkt('MULTILINESTRING ((1 1, 6 1))'))
pr.addFeature(record)

text_format = QgsTextFormat()
label = QgsPalLayerSettings()
label.fieldName = 'Description'
label.enabled = True
label.setFormat(text_format)

# --
label.placement = QgsPalLayerSettings.Line
# --

labeler = QgsVectorLayerSimpleLabeling(label)
layer.setLabelsEnabled(True)
layer.setLabeling(labeler)
layer.triggerRepaint()

QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
```

Comment: I verified that the solution works and it has solved my original problem.  I suspect that there maybe another approach by somehow refreshing the layer as well, but, I wasn't able to solve it.

Answer (score 3):

There was the same problem. QGIS 3.4.8. Tried to change `label.placement` to `QgsPalLayerSettings.Line` or `QgsPalLayerSettings.Curved` or `QgsPalLayerSettings.Horizontal`. Labels became visible only after running "Labels" dialog.
In my case, I used string expression for labeling, not field value. In this case, have to set this flag manually:

```
layerSettings = QgsPalLayerSettings()
layerSettings.isExpression = True
```

"Labels" dialog sets this flag on automatically. To find this, I exported style to .qml before and after run dialog and compared results.