# PyQGIS to set masked symbol layer and mask source

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-3, pyqgis-3

I have a PyQGIS script to open a GPKG-layer (contour lines) along with a qml-file in QGIS.
In the style file I have enabled label masking and using the contour lines as mask layer:

[image]

[image]

Making my labels look like this:

[image]

However, after running the python-file, the style is as expected (as given in the qml-file), but without the masking (label masking information is not stored in the qml-file?):

[image]

My code so far where I have not figured out how to set "Masked symbol layers" and "Mask sources":

```
# Add geopackage
fileName = "karplantehoyder.gpkg"
layer = QgsVectorLayer(fileName, "hoyder", "ogr")
label = QgsPalLayerSettings()
label.MaskEnabled = True
# masklayer = QgsMaskMarkerSymbolLayer()  #? How do i set the mask symbol layer and mask source
# masklayer.setMasks("hoyder")            # This is not working, have tried id and layer - not working
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer, True) 
# Load style
layer.loadNamedStyle('./qml/n5hoyder.qml')  # color, line width, label font/size set, but not mask
layer.saveStyleToDatabase(layer.name(),'style n5hoyder',True,'')
```

How may I do this with PyQGIS-code?

**Update**: I have also tried to use `QgsTextMaskSettings`, but I can't figure out how to set the mask layer to be `"hoyder"` and symbol to be lines.

I have also discovered a strange behaviour? Masks may be set in the layer hoyder's Layer Properties and still be unchecked in Layer styling, and the mask will appear.

[image]

If only set in the Layer Styling and not in the Layer Properties, the mask will not appear.

[image]

Comment: [This](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/321029) 
post may help you.

Comment: @Mayo, thanks for the link which I already had a look at. The post is from 2019 while masking came in 3.12 released 2020-02-21, I believe. I could not find anything regarding mask in the code in the post, and besides, my labels appear. Just the mask is missing. https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog312/index.html#labelling

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update QGIS ver. 3.30** (see thread on https://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/qgis-user/2023-April/052905.html)

You may still use the code from Kadir Şahbaz above, but you need to add two procedures and change the code-line for setting the mask (****).

This is working for me in ver. 3.30:

```
def get_symbollayer(layer, ruleId, symbollayer_ids):
    """
    Returns the symbol layer according to given layer, ruleId (None if no rule) and the path
    to symbol layer id (for instance [0, 1])
    """
    renderer = layer.renderer()
    symbol = None
    if renderer.type() == "categorizedSymbol":
        i = renderer.categoryIndexForValue(ruleId)
        cat = renderer.categories()[i]
        symbol = cat.symbol()
    elif renderer.type() == "singleSymbol":
        symbol = renderer.symbol()

    symbollayer = symbol.symbolLayer(symbollayer_ids[0])
    for i in range(1, len(symbollayer_ids)):
        symbol = symbollayer.subSymbol()
        symbollayer = symbol.symbolLayer(symbollayer_ids[i])

    return symbollayer

def get_symbollayer_ref(layer, ruleId, symbollayer_ids):
       """
       Returns the symbol layer according to given layer, ruleId (None if no rule) and the path
       to symbol layer id (for instance [0, 1])
       """
       symbollayer = get_symbollayer(layer, ruleId, symbollayer_ids)
       return QgsSymbolLayerReference(layer.id(), symbollayer.id())
```

...

```
fileName = "./gpkg/karplantehoyder.gpkg"
layer = QgsVectorLayer(fileName, "hoyder", "ogr")
layer.loadNamedStyle('./qml/n5hoyder.qml')      # Load qml
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer, False) # Add layer False to be able
root.insertLayer(4,layer)                       # to specify a custom position
label_settings = layer.labeling().settings()    # Get current settings of the layer
text_format = label_settings.format()           # Get text format of the settings
text_format.mask().setMaskedSymbolLayers([get_symbollayer_ref(layer,"",[0])])  # set masked symbol layers ****
```

...

Answer (score 10):

> Label masking information is not stored in the qml-file?

I guess "Masked symbol layers" and "Mask sources" settings are not stored in both qml file and Geopackage. I just realized that.

One solution would be as follows:

- Load qml file
- Get layer labeling mask settings
- Set masked symbol layers
- Apply the setting to the layer

```
# Add layer
fileName = "karplantehoyder.gpkg"
layer = QgsVectorLayer(fileName, "hoyder", "ogr")
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer, True) 

# Load qml
layer.loadNamedStyle('./qml/n5hoyder.qml')

# Get current settings of the layer
label_settings = layer.labeling().settings()
# If you use labeling() method before loading qml, you get error
# Because labeling is not enabled for the layer before loading qml


# Get text format of the settings
text_format = label_settings.format()

# Set masked symbol layers
text_format.mask().setMaskedSymbolLayers([
    QgsSymbolLayerReference(layer.id(), QgsSymbolLayerId("", 0))])

# Set format
label_settings.setFormat(text_format)

# Set settings
layer.labeling().setSettings(label_settings)
```

[image]

Documentation:

- [Class: QgsTextFormat](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsTextFormat.html?#module-QgsTextFormat)
- [Class: QgsTextMaskSettings](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsTextMaskSettings.html#module-QgsTextMaskSettings)
- [Class: QgsVectorLayerSimpleLabeling](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsVectorLayerSimpleLabeling.html#module-QgsVectorLayerSimpleLabeling)

Comment: Excellent! Nicely explained to a pyQGIS newbie like me. Works like a charm. Now, I finally see what setMaskedSymbolLayers(self, maskedLayers: Iterable[QgsSymbolLayerReference]) means and how to assign the parameters. This will hopefully help me in the future when reading QGIS API documentation. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, the class QgsSymbolLayerReference has changed in QGIS ver. 3.30 (https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.30/core/QgsSymbolLayerReference.html#qgis.core.QgsSymbolLayerReference). Thus the code above don't work in ver. 3.30. So far I haven't figured out how to change the code to make it work.